# 'Number of referencing columns in foreign key differs from number of referenced columns' CONFUSION

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a foreign key and am getting an error that I can't figure out.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblFiscalYear(
  FiscalYear nchar(4) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblFiscalYear PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.tblDivisonMemberCE(
  DivMemberCEID int IDENTITY NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblDivisionMemberCE PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  DivMemberID int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblDivisionMemberCE_tblDivisionMember FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.tblDivisionMember(DivMemberID),
  FiscalYear nchar(4) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblDivisionMemberCE_tblFiscalYear FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.tblFiscalYear(FiscalYear),
  CENumber tinyint NOT NULL,
  CEDescripID int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblDivisionMemberCE_tblCEDescription FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.tblCEDescription(CEDescripID)
);
```

The other tables (tblDivisionMember, tblCEDescription) have been created with an int PK.  tblFiscalYear has already been created as well using the code shown.  I chose to only have one column since each entry would be unique anyway.  I'm wondering if that's the problem.

Here is the error message:

> Number of referencing columns in foreign key differs from number of referenced columns, table 'dbo.tblDivisonMemberCE'.

The error is coming from the line of code:

> CONSTRAINT FK_tblDivisionMemberCE_tblFiscalYear FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.tblFiscalYear(FiscalYear),

The other FKs seem to be ok.  And I just don't get it, b/c there is only one column referenced!  Something else is afoot!  I don't have proper dba training so I am wondering if there is something simple I am missing.  I can't seem to internet sleuth my way to the answer so I'm hoping someone here will know.

I am wondering if I need to recreate tblFiscalYear with a traditional IDENTITY int PK.

Thank you for your time,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

You are combining a column constraint and a table constraint.

See the [full syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#full-syntax):

- Column constraints are done in line with columns.
- Table constraints are declared after all the columns and are separated with a comma.

[image]

You have an extra comma here, which makes the parser think you are done with the column and are declaring a table constraint - which also has to specify the referencing column(s).

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma at the end of the line where `FiscalYear` is defined. If you remove it, it will work without error:

```
FiscalYear nchar(4) NOT NULL   -- comma removed
  CONSTRAINT FK_tblDivisionMemberCE_tblFiscalYear FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.tblFiscalYear(FiscalYear),
```

There are two main ways to define a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. First one is to put it in the column definition, as you did with all other foreign key constraints. So the column, its datatype, the `NULL` or `NOT NULL` and the FK constraint all need to be between commas or the enclosing parentheses. When you add a comma, the two parts are parsed as different column/constraint definitions.

The 2nd method is to separate the column from the FK definition. This is just a different approach (sometimes preferred if we want to have all the columns first, then the constraints, PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, FOREIGN KEY and CHECK). It's also the only method for defining FOREIGN KEY constraint with 2 or more referencing columns and any other constraints that involves 2 or more columns (e.g. composite UNIQUE).

Your case with the 2nd method would be:

```
FiscalYear nchar(4) NOT NULL,   -- comma here
-- ...
-- there might be other definitions in between
--
CONSTRAINT FK_tblDivisionMemberCE_tblFiscalYear 
    FOREIGN KEY (FiscalYear)     -- FK columns added here
    REFERENCES dbo.tblFiscalYear(FiscalYear),
```